# javascript web worker posting message

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, web-worker

I'm having an intense processing at a chuck of my script, so in order to not block the UI and avoid browsers processing cap (12.5 on chrome) i've tried web worker

problem is that the object is too big and contains arrays
so the post message won't transfer it with throwing 
"Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': An object could not be cloned"

so i thought about stringifying it, object wasn't fully transferred as it contains arrays, and arrays where stringified to "[]"

so i thought about converting arrays to strings/objects to be able to transfer them then back but as the object is big, i run out of memory on stack (even with third party plugins)

so is there something i'm missing that would help in this situation ?

- any better way to process the time consuming function without
  blocking the ui and allow me to report progress back; would solve
  this
- any way to transfer the object to the web worker with all of it's
  objects and arrays; would solve this

[debugging picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmZmN.png)

[the sub object that isn't stringified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM8by.png)

Comment: `object wasn't fully transferred as it contains arrays, and arrays where stringified to "[]"` that sounds like a misinterpretation of the results ... arrays are easily stringified ... can you explain what sort of object you are trying to work with - can you also explain why you've tagged `node.js` when the question is clearly browser related

Comment: well it's an array of objects inside my main object, it doesn't stringify it (debugged on chrome dev tools, object is fully populated and it doesn't get fully stringified after the json stringify call)

Comment: `debugged on chrome dev tools` don't always trust what you see in the console - if JSON.stringify doesn't throw an error, then you can almost be sure it worked

Comment: You still didn't explain what **type** of object you are dealing with - if it contains DOM elements, then `JSON.stringify` wont give you the whole enchilada

Comment: i've added a picture while debugging from chrome dev tools

Comment: yeah, you've circled "circles" on the left and circled an empty array called "shapes" on the right ... I can't see how an empty `shapes` property relates to a non-empty `circles` property

Comment: i've added another picture of an object that didn't get stringified to explain furthur why i marked it, not a dom object or a weird one for that matter :\

Comment: well, that's one of the `circles` and, yeah, there's no reference to `circles` in the portion of the stringified output in the first picture

Comment: don't expect the stringified object keys to be in alphabetical order - JSON.stringify does not re-order the keys, but the console log of an object does show keys in alphabetical order

Comment: yeah, any suggestion :D ? well tbh i don't care for the web worker or stringified for that matter, even a solution for the main problem of heavy function blocking the ui would still help :D

Comment: i've checked the whole output, doesn't contain it anywhere, wanna data dump ?

Comment: without seeing what the processing involves, I can only suggest processing "chunks" in an asynchronous fashion

Comment: `i've checked the whole output` - remember that console.log of a string (the stringified object) won't necessarily be complete - I know in firefox you have to click on the [...] at the end of a long string in the console to see the whole thing

Comment: been debugging for couple of hours with different tools, it's just not working and i'm not experienced enough to debug further in, ill do async chucks if no one came up with a better solution, it's just that the function have too many loops that is nested too deep, would be hell but yeah if it's the only way out, ill take it

Comment: let me ask this ... how big is the data? I know you have objects within arrays several layers deep, but can you give some sort of qualification to the size of the data - it may well be that your processing is inefficient in some way (how many lines in the processing code?)

Comment: less than 100 lines, it's basically array of circles, each circle contain pixels, you get the pixels of all circles, add the new pixels to the list and you have the area of all the circles intersecting.
data is not that big, probably less than 1kb, only optimization i found was to add duplicated pixels and remove them later rather than checking in a nested loop (which tbh didn't make much as the list increase gradually and start from 0)

Comment: the only optimization is to not use circles and find a decent algorithm to get me the pixels of the area around an irregular shape with a certain stroke around it, any idea ?

Comment: The Shape object is coming from a `Shape` constructor. Can you check if that also defines a `toJSON` ? If one is available it will be used for serialization.

Comment: not really, used 
if(window.Prototype) {
    delete Object.prototype.toJSON;
    delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
    delete Hash.prototype.toJSON;
    delete String.prototype.toJSON;
}
and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, do you get the object recreated correctly?

On your main thread:

```
var worker = new Worker('myworkerfile.js')
worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify(myclusters))
```

On the worker thread:

```
onmessage =  function(e) {
  var myclusters = JSON.parse(e.data);
  console.log(myclusters)
}
```